# cv2.imread() returns NoneType

Tags: python, opencv, discord.py

So I've seen few solutions on internet, but each of them recomends using other libraries f.e. `matplotlib` if this one doesn't work, but I would like to know if it's maybe possible to repair it, cause I could use `opencv` image manipulation functions in further part of a code, so I would be glad if there was anyway to stay with `opencv` image import.
Here's my code:

```
        if len(message.attachments) == 0:
            print('[INFO] Message doesn\'t contain any attachments')
            pass
        else:
            print('[INFO] Message contains attachments')
            dir = os.listdir(path)
            for filename in dir:
                i = 0
                img = cv2.imread(path + filename)
                for attachment in message.attachments:
                    img2 = cv2.imread(attachment.url)
                    print(attachment.url)
                    print(img)
                    print(img2)
                    if img2 == img:
                        print('[LOG] It\' same as ' + filename)
                        await message.delete()
                        await message.channel.send("You've reapeated Image")
                    else:
                        print('[LOG] User sent appropriate image')
```

`message` is an `message` object from `discord.py`, representing last image sent by specified user;
`message.attachments` is a list of images send with `message` object;
I've tried both `attachment.url` and `attachment.proxy_url`, but neither of them works;
EDIT: I've forgot to add, that both images, the one from path, and the one from url, are registered as `None`

Comment: Each time you have this kind of error, it means that opencv can't find any image. What happen if you print(attachment.url) ? Maybe you should take a look there  https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/02/convert-url-to-image-with-python-and-opencv/

Comment: @Panda50 it just print's the image url, and it is working, just fine, when I open it manualy

Comment: It happens sometimes with direct link, try to save the file to local and then try it out, if it still fails then try to read the image with lesser fixed resolution like 640x480.

Comment: You need to join the path, now you're doing something like this `"C:/something" + "filename.png"` the result is `"C:/somethingfilename.png`, you need to add the `/`, one way is  `os.path.join(path, filename)`